# Update Opportunity Using rest API; Error : 400 bad request in response

Tags: rest-api, c#, connected-apps, .net

Example for creating Opportunity :

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0AASSFGSEID -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @newrecord.json -X PATCH
```

Example request body newrecord.json file :

```
{ "Name":"FFNEw","CloseDate":"2015/02/04","StageName":"Prospecting","Probability":10 }
```

My ASP.net code :

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token); client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)(HttpWebRequest.Create(token.instance_url + "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0AASSFGSEID"));
request.Method = "PATCH";
using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
  requestWriter.Write(json);
  requestWriter.Flush();
  requestWriter.Close();
}
var response = request.GetResponse();
}
```

Getting Error 400 Bad Request in "request.GetResponse()".

Comment: Make sure your token has been url decoded first - in the past I've forgotten to urldecode the token and it contained a '!' character, which I posted back still encoded (causing it to get encoded twice)

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)(HttpWebRequest.Create(token.instance_url + "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0AASSFGSEID?_HttpMethod=PATCH"));
```

I have just added **?_HttpMethod=PATCH** in request url and it's working for me..

Comment: That is how it is described in this [guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_rest.pdf) Pages(49-50)